# reason to subclass your own resouce for tastypie

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

I've seen test codes where custom resources are further subclassed. 
But it was for the `test` sake, not for any real use.

Why would anyone want to subclass a resource for obvious reason(but apparently not to me)?

An example would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into a situation where I need to subclass a resource.
I have a django model that has several subclasses like so (I've simplified it a lot):

```
class Information(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField)

class Question(Information):
    question = models.CharField)

class Link(Information):
    url = models.CharField()
```

I want an API for accessing all of the Information objects, but still want to be able to access all the subclass specific attributes for each subclass. In this case I'd want to have 3 resources:

```
class InformationResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Information.objects.all()

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        '''Add some extra meta data here'''

class QuestionResource(InformationResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Question.objects.all()

class LinkResource(InformationResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Link.objects.all()
```

This way I have an api for returning all Information objects (as well as the attributes that are common to all of them), but if I need to access subclass specific attributes I can access them through their subclass resource APIs. Furthermore, these subclassed Resources will have access to all of the methods defined for their superclass. For instance, they can override the superclass' dehydrate method to add more fields.